# estoy aplicando este proceso almacenado en mysql y solo necesito que si el ID del producto no existe me lo inserte en la tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE registroalmacen(
p_id_pro INT,
id_almacen INT,
p_stock INT,
p_present INT
)
begin   
    declare filtroApli int;
set filtroApli = (select id_pro from almacen where id_pro = p_id_pro);
    
if  filtroApli = p_id_pro then
select * from almacen;
else 
 INSERT INTO almacen VALUES(p_id_pro, id_almacen,p_stock,p_present);
END if;
    
END//
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es poder el id como auto incrementado, para que cada vez que haya una inserción de datos le ponga el id

Comment: Gracias amigo pero ya encontré la solución, solo era colocar en el if " NOT EXISTS" con un select   ---->   IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT id_pro,id_almac_info from almacen WHERE id_pro = p_id_pro and id_almac_info = id_almacen) then
INSERT INTO almacen(id_pro, id_almac_info, stock, present)
VALUES ( p_id_pro,id_almacen,p_stock,p_present);
ELSE
SELECT 'Este producto ya existe en la base de datos!';
END IF;

Comment: La solución `IF ... THEN INSERT ... ELSE ... ENDIF` no soporta procesamiento paralelo. Si hay múltiples procesos insertando simultáneamente, podría no ser efectiva.

Answer (score 0):

La solución más conveniente es la de agregar una restricción `UNIQUE` de base de datos para la columna.

Por ejemplo:

```
alter table almacen add constraint uq1 unique (p_id_pro);
```